# search values in another column and get corresponding value python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZH8L.png)

Hello everyone,
I need to ask from the picture attached. I want to search the values of parent TT in ticketNumber and get the Severity of parent TTs.

Severity of TicketNumber column is given. Want to search for parent tt

Comment: please can you provide the image in proper code format so users can copy it and run it themselves so they can find out what the problem is

Comment: Please post sample input with expected output.